# How to retrieve empty json array by Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have table `item` which has a JSON column `sku_purchase_price`. There are some rows like that:

[image]

I tried to retrieve those rows from DB by Eloquent:

```
$items = Item::where('sku_purchase_price', '[]')->get();
```

but it returns a collection with zero results.

So, how to retrieve those row from DB by Eloquent?

Comment: you can convert the data in 'sku_purchase_price' to strings so you retrieve strings, but why do you have [] in the rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um there is something not quite right in your code base earlier on if it's inserting ***empty arrays***.

You need to find the code that is inserting into this table and check if there is an empty array being created and if there is, **pass through an empty string** or nothing if it's not a required field.

However if you want to select them using Eloquent you would do:

```
$items = Item::where('sku_purchase_price', '\[\]')->get();
```

But yes, don't do this, *find the actual problem* in your code first rather than trying to select empty arrays from the db...

Comment: what should i do if i need to get empty downloads data only?  $patternsRelated->whereRaw('download != "" AND download != "[]"')->orderBy($sortby)->get();

Comment: i am using the code mention in above comment but still i am getting empty download data.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereJsonLength`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereJsonLength) like this:

```
$items = Item::whereJsonLength('sku_purchase_price', 0)->get();
```

This works only with MySQL 5.7, PostgreSQL, SQL Server 2016, and SQLite 3.9.0 *(with the [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html))*.